# How to build boost::asio::experimental

Tags: boost, boost-asio, c++17

I want to build an example from the page: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/chat_server.cpp

G++ version: 7.3
Boost version 1.69

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio/experimental.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::experimental::awaitable;
using boost::asio::experimental::co_spawn;
using boost::asio::experimental::detached;
using boost::asio::experimental::redirect_error;
namespace this_coro = boost::asio::experimental::this_coro;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_participant
{
public:
  virtual ~chat_participant() {}
  virtual void deliver(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_room
{
public:
  void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
  {
    participants_.insert(participant);
    for (auto msg: recent_msgs_)
      participant->deliver(msg);
  }

  void leave(chat_participant_ptr participant)
  {
    participants_.erase(participant);
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
      recent_msgs_.pop_front();

    for (auto participant: participants_)
      participant->deliver(msg);
  }

private:
  std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
  enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
  std::deque<std::string> recent_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_session
  : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
  chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room)
    : socket_(std::move(socket)),
      timer_(socket_.get_executor().context()),
      room_(room)
  {
    timer_.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
  }

  void start()
  {
    room_.join(shared_from_this());

    co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
        [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->reader(); },
        detached);

    co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
        [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->writer(); },
        detached);
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    timer_.cancel_one();
  }

private:
  awaitable<void> reader()
  {
    auto token = co_await this_coro::token();

    try
    {
      for (std::string read_msg;;)
      {
        std::size_t n = co_await boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
            boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", token);

        room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
        read_msg.erase(0, n);
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  awaitable<void> writer()
  {
    auto token = co_await this_coro::token();

    try
    {
      while (socket_.is_open())
      {
        if (write_msgs_.empty())
        {
          boost::system::error_code ec;
          co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(token, ec));
        }
        else
        {
          co_await boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
              boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), token);
          write_msgs_.pop_front();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  void stop()
  {
    room_.leave(shared_from_this());
    socket_.close();
    timer_.cancel();
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
  chat_room& room_;
  std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

awaitable<void> listener(tcp::acceptor acceptor)
{
  auto token = co_await this_coro::token();

  chat_room room;

  for (;;)
  {
    std::make_shared<chat_session>(
        co_await acceptor.async_accept(token),
        room
      )->start();
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc < 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context(1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      unsigned short port = std::atoi(argv[i]);
      co_spawn(io_context,
          [&]{ return listener(tcp::acceptor(io_context, {tcp::v4(), port})); },
          detached);
    }

    boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto){ io_context.stop(); });

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
../src/ChatServer.cpp:28:34: error: ‘boost::asio::experimental::awaitable’ has not been declared
../src/ChatServer.cpp:29:34: error: ‘boost::asio::experimental::co_spawn’ has not been declared
../src/ChatServer.cpp:32:50: error: ‘this_coro’ is not a namespace-name
```

Answer (score 4):

I have updated my boost to 1.70+ and successfully build the coroutine ts examples. Although some API has changed and there is no `experimental` header/namespace now, the build configuration is almost the same.

Dependency:

- Compiler: Clang 8+
- (Optional) CMake

[chat server.cpp, example in 1.70](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/chat_server.cpp)

CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(chat_server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines-ts --stdlib=libc++ -Xclang -fconcepts-ts")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system)

include_directories(
        ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(chat_server chat_server.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cpptest
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        pthread
)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, be sure to define `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT` to get the [experimental bits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutines_ts.html) (apparently, you didn't, looking at your error messages).

Secondly, GCC 7.3 doesn't have the experimental coroutine support.

- Wandbox: Gcc 7.3 https://wandbox.org/permlink/WV7eqS908GbnbM2k

Use a later compiler or do not use the experimental coroutine support.

Note: Gcc HEAD 9.x (2018012) on Wandbox does not appear to support this yet

- Wandbox: Gcc 9.x https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZnH7fX9p4PcXnDPN

Comment: just curious. I just stumbled upon this problem in asio coro example. but how come boost::beast uses coroutines and stackless coros in examples and this works on linux? I clearly see they use different includes, but what goes on in boost coro implementation that in case on asio it doesnt work and in beast it does? though beast uses asio... I'm lost here :)

Comment: Do you have a link @kreuzerkrieg? I don't know what you mean, really (what problem do you get, what do they include etc.)

Comment: I mean this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html#beast.examples.servers and this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp17_examples.html Already got the difference, beast uses coro and asio uses `TS` coro which would not work with GCC

Comment: It does help to use the proper names instead of abbreviating everything in a hurry :) "Beast uses Boost Coroutine" actually says what you mean, contrary to "beast uses coro". Likewise, it's not obvious that you mean "Boost Asio uses the coroutines TS" (as opposed to standalone Asio), but I'll assume the former.