# Visual Studio complains about co_await in author's Boost Asio examples

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Boost Asio. I've played around with callbacks and everything worked well. However, now I'm trying to switch to coroutines and I'm facing a problem with `co_await`. Visual Studio 2017 Community edition says `"this co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function and none was found"`.

The code I'm using is the author's examples on Boost Asio website. Link:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server.cpp

The only modification I made to the code is `#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT` at the very first line of the file.

Why am I getting this error `"this co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function and none was found"` on every occurrence of `co_await`? The author's examples should work without any problems, right? Am I missing an `#include` or something?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you add that line? Presumably the macro was left undefined in your environment for a reason? e.g. no suitable "await_ready" function is available.

Comment: First Google result for `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT` is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/19/using-c-coroutines-with-boost-c-libraries/ which gives you a compiler switch to try...

Comment: I added that line to enable the experimental bits as described here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882914/how-to-build-boostasioexperimental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882914/how-to-build-boostasioexperimental)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Lightness Races in Orbit for suggesting to try a compiler switch, that was the main problem, although I had a few others. If anyone encounters a similar problem, these are the steps I took:

1. Move `#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT` to the header file, in my case pch.h (dumb mistake)
2. Add `/await` switch to `Project Properties > C/C++ > Command Line > Additional Options`.

At this point, everything compiled without errors. However, the `co_await` remains underlined in red because:

> Intellisense compiler has not caught up with MSVC compiler yet.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/19/using-c-coroutines-with-boost-c-libraries/

Comment: Note that now the /await is not required as of VS 15.8